# Hi: the following code that should prints a correspondng season based on the value presented on the variable season_num: the code not working properly

Tags: python

```py
season_num = [1, 2, 3, 4]

if not season_num:
    input('Please enter a valid num: ')
else:

    for i in season_num:
        input('give a num: ')
        if i == 1:
            print('Spring')
        elif i == 2:
            print('Summer')
        elif i == 3:
            print('Fall')
        else:
            print('Winter')
```

Comment: You're asking for input but not assigning it to a variable.

Comment: If you're looping through the `season_num` list, why do you need the user to give a number?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. It's not clear what you're asking exactly and what you're trying to accomplish. You'll probably need to make a [mre] including some example input and the desired output for it, as well as the current output for completeness. You can [edit] if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're probably trying to do is this:

```
seasonNum = input('give a num: ')
if seasonNum == "1":
    print('Spring')
elif seasonNum == "2":
    print('Summer')
elif seasonNum == "3":
    print('Fall')
elif seasonNum == "4":
    print('Winter')
else:
    print('invalid selection')
```

However, a better way to do this is to use a dictionary:

```
seasons = {
    "1": "Spring",
    "2": "Summer",
    "3": "Fall",
    "4": "Winter"
}
seasonNum = input('give a num: ')
selectedSeason = seasons.get(seasonNum)
print(selectedSeason or "invalid selection")
```

Comment: You forgot `int()` in the first block

Comment: Well you changed the opposite of what I suggested, but that does work, though why use strings for numeric values? OP's using ints.

Comment: input() returns a string and casting to int without input validation is dangerous.

Comment: How is it dangerous? The program will just crash if it gets bad input.

Comment: Letting the program crash because of a bad cast results in two (uncontrolled) behaviours in the code. One at the cast -> where it would crash, and the other where they enter something other than 1-4, and get "invalid selection". I just think it's unnecessary to cast here.